# Как получить элемент массива внутри Map?

Tags: массивы, kotlin, arraylist, map

Как получить элемент массива внутри Map?

```
var vegetables = mutableMapOf<String, IntArray>()
vegetables["apple"] = intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Когда делаешь println, выдает адрес в памяти

```
println(vegetables["apple"])
```

Когда делаешь println таким образом, выдает нулевой символ, но не элемент:

```
println(vegetables["apple"].toString()[0])
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html#map, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/map-operations.html#retrieve-keys-and-values

Answer (score 1):

В языке Kotlin метод `[]` это то же самое, что и метод `get()`. Почитайте подробнее про модификатор [`operator`](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/operator-overloading.html).

Таким образом, этот код:

```kotlin
vegetables["apple"][0]
```

Можно написать так:

```kotlin
vegetables.get("apple").get(0)
```

Проблема заключается лишь в том, что первый метод `get` возвращает [нуллабельный](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/null-safety.html) тип, поэтому используйте оператор безопасного вызова [`?.`](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls), вместо обычной точки:

```kotlin
vegetables.get("apple")?.get(0)
```